# How to keep qtip fixed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, qtip

I'm using qtip for jQuery, and I have the following code

```
$('#content a[href]').qtip(
   {
      content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip', // Give it some content, in this case a simple string
       style: { 
      name: 'cream', // Inherit from preset style
      tip: 'topLeft'
      },
      show: {
            when: 'click', // Show it on click...
            solo: true // ...and hide all others when its shown
      },
      hide: {
          when : 'focusout',
          fixed: true
      }
   });
```

The desired effect is that the tip should display when I click on the link and stay there unless if I click on some other part of the page (hence the focusout), but at the same time if I click on the tip itself, I don't want it to disappear so that I can insert interesting stuff in it, hence the fixed: true... but then even when I do this it would still disappear when I click on the tip... what am I doing wrong or is there another way to prevent the tip from disappearing when I click on it but have it disappear if I click on another part of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `unfocus` event:

```
$('#content a[href]').qtip({
    content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip',
    // Give it some content, in this case a simple string
    style: {
        name: 'cream',
        // Inherit from preset style
        tip: 'topLeft'
    },
    show: {
        when: 'click',
        // Show it on click...
        solo: true // ...and hide all others when its shown
    },
    hide: {
         when: { event: 'unfocus' }
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rep87/

From the [documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#hide):

> The 'unfocus' event hides the tooltip when anywhere else on the document, except the tooltip itself, is clicked.

---

Comment: hmm interesting, when I do that on my code, the qtip won't disappear when I click on some other place...it only disappears if I click on the link twice.....the demo seems to work though....any thoughts?

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: What version of qTip and jQuery are you using? The demo is using jQuery 1.4.4 (although it seems to work with any version >= 1.3.2 except 1.4.2) and the latest version of qTip.  Is there any way you could duplicate the issue in a fiddle? If not, could it be something with other code?

Comment: yea I'm using jquery 1.4.2, but I'm also using the jquery.qtip-1.0 revised version which supposedly works on 1.4.2 (and it does for the most part).....i'll try updating jquery and see what happens

Comment: yea...updated jquery and used the rc3 of qtip...it seems to work now...thanks